# timer is not counting up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/640/

In jsfiddle I have, what I am having issue with is the response time. It is going up by 2 seconds rather than 1 second. I believe the issue with this is because I have 2 questions so it counts the seconds for both questions in each response time text input and hence it goes up by 2 seconds each time. But my question is how to sort this out so timer is counting up normally:

Code for response time:

`
     var response = "00:00:00",
         responseparts = response.split(':'),
         responsehours = +responseparts[0],
         responseminutes = +responseparts[1],
         responseseconds = +responseparts[2];

```
     function correctResponse(responsenum) {
         return (responsenum < 10) ? ("0" + responsenum) : responsenum;
     }

 var responsetimer = [];
 $('.queWrap').each(function(index, element) {
 var wrap=$(this),   
 input = wrap.find('.responseTime'),
 checkbox=wrap.find('#ck-button').find('input'),
 clickInput=wrap.find('.mouseClick');


     responsetimer[index] = setInterval(function () {
     responseseconds++;
     if (responseseconds == 60) {
         responseseconds = 00;
         responseminutes++;

         if (responseminutes == 60) {
             responseminutes = 00;
             responsehours++;

             if (responsehours <= 24) {
                 clearInterval(responsetimer);
                 return;
             }

         }
     }
     input.val(correctResponse(responsehours) + ":" + correctResponse(responseminutes) + ":" + correctResponse(responseseconds));
 }, 1000);
```

`

Comment: You've been working on this for awhile eh? jsfiddle count is at 640. That's a record.

Comment: @mrtsherman A lot of testing haha, I just use same fiddle for different testing and keep notes on numbers, like this one is 640

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the var declarations for

```
response = "00:00:00",
responseparts = response.split(':'),
responsehours = +responseparts[0],
responseminutes = +responseparts[1],
responseseconds = +responseparts[2];
```

inside the each callback

http://jsfiddle.net/h8srH/1/

Also, change your ck-button id's to classes. Id's are meant to be unique.